# How to take text input with DialogFragment in Android in the fragment itself

Tags: android

[ [How to take text input with DialogFragment in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501272/how-to-take-text-input-with-dialogfragment-in-android) ]
here in this question same as mine we bring out the text from the `editText` in the `MainActivity` .

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listener = (AddcustomerListener) getActivity();
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_customer_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   /////////////here////////////

                    EditText user = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    Log.i( "sad",user.getText().toString());
                    //listener.onDialogAddCustomer(AddCustomerDialog.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

I used the approach we use in a `ViewHolder` of a `RecyclerView` adapter to access the elements .
I had multiple `editTexts` and was trying to work around , my code works but is there any harm in using the builder's view this way to access the edit text .
Still learning :)

Comment: You want to get Input Text values from `DialogFragment` to your `Fragment` when your `DialogFragment` is closed. Is this what you want?

Comment: Create interface and pass data into the interested party from your DialogFragment. Don't directly refer to another Fragment by findviewbyid

Comment: @Sreehari why not ? where else do I access the editText and how ? I have an Interface available below the very concerned line of code .